# Show result of only one CQL filter in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, cql-filter

I am using with OL3. I can dynamically change URL CQL WFS layer from my GeoServer but I want to know how to use `map.removelayer` before adding another CQL and zoom extend to selected CQL feature.

Below is my sample code:

```
$("#district").change(function() {
    
    var statekod=document.getElementById("district").value;
    var cqlFilter='ngdp='+ statekod ;
    var urlTemplate =   'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/TM/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&' +
                    'typename=TM:Daerah&' +
                    'CQL_FILTER='+ cqlFilter + '&' +    
                    'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +                    
                    'format_options=callback:gotFetch'; 

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: urlTemplate,
      });                   

        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
            width: 1 
          })
        }),
        
      });

    console.log(vectorSource);
     map.addLayer(vector);  
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what is not working? is there an error message?

Comment: after cql how to zoom to the filter layer and only show 1 filter...right now my code only add new cql to previous layer

Answer (score 1):

If you use a url function to apply the `cqlFilter` to the template you can simply refresh the source after changing `cqlFilter` (if using an OpenLayers version before 6 you need to clear the source before refreshing).

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function() {
      return 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/TM/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&' +
                'typename=TM:Daerah&' +
                'CQL_FILTER='+ cqlFilter + '&' +    
                'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +                    
                'format_options=callback:gotFetch';
    },
  }); 


cqlFilter = newValue;
vectorSource.refresh();
```

Comment: i got this error when using this code "Uncaught ReferenceError: newValue is not defined" thx for helping sir...your code much simpler than mine